# In Rails, what's the difference between find_each and where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In Rails, both [find_each](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each) and [where](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) are used for retrieving data from Database supported by ActiveRecord.

You can pass your query condition to `where`, like:

```
c = Category.where(:name => 'Ruby', :position => 1)
```

And you can pass batch size to `find_each`, like:

```
Hedgehog.find_each(batch_size: 50).map{ |p| p.to_json }
```

But what's the difference between the following 2 code?

```
# code 1
Person.where("age > 21").find_each(batch_size: 50) do |person|
  # processing
end

# code 2
Person.where("age > 21").each do |person|
  # processing
end
```

Does code 1 batch retrieve 50 tuples each time, and code 2 retrieve all tuples in one time? More details explaination is welcomed.

My opinion is:

1. both `where` and `find_each` can be used for batch retrieving, but user can define batch size when using `find_each`.
2. `find_each` does not support passing query condition.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

An active record relation does not automatically load all records into memory.

When you call `#each`, all records will be loaded into memory. When you call `#find_each`, records will be loaded into memory in batches of the given batch size.

So when your query returns a number of records that would be too much memory for the server's available resources, then using `#find_each` would be a great choice.

It's basically like using ruby's lazy enumeration `#to_enum#lazy` with `#each_slice` and then `#each` (very convenient).

Comment: So code 1 may execute SQL multiple times(according to records size and batch size), code 2 only execute SQL once?

Comment: Yes that is my understanding. If you look at your development log or look at the sql output in rails console you'll see something like `Users.for_each(batch_size) {|u| }` `SELECT "users"."*" FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id"  > 51)`  `SELECT "users"."*" FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id"  > 51) LIMIT 50` ... and so on

Comment: `users = User.where(:birth_day < Date.today)` if we call this line, we didn't call `#each`. but are you sure that we don't load all data into `users` variable?

Answer (score 2):

Answering Jin Lim's question.
The statement `users = User.where(:birth_day < Date.today)` does not load all the data in users variable as the statement has not executed yet and is due to lazy loading supported by Rails. When you call `each` on users, then all of the data would be loaded into memory.